# How to display a pdf with cocoa swift (version 3.1)

Tags: swift, cocoa, pdf, quartz

I'm trying to make a PDF viewer for mac (NOT IOS) for an assignment but I can't even figure out how to get a PDF to actually show up. We have to use PDFView and Quartz.
Most tutorials I've seen on this topic use something like:

```
view.setDocument(pdf)
```

But swift says PDFView has no member setDocument. I looked through the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview) and the only thing that even remotely looks like it would work was setCurrentSelection so I tried:

```
import Cocoa
import Quartz

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var PDFV: PDFView!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        let fileURL:URL = (Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "pdf")! as NSURL) as URL
        let pdfDocument:PDFDocument = PDFDocument.self.init(url: fileURL as URL)!
        let thing:PDFSelection = PDFSelection.self.init(document: pdfDocument)
        PDFV.setCurrentSelection(thing, animate: true)
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

But this causes the window to crash when I run it and xcode says:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode 0x0). Does anyone know what I'm actually meant to use?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to mention the error shows up on the setCurrentSelection line

Comment: i think you had better to use `webView ` for showing pdf

Comment: It is an assignment, and we are required to use PDFView.

Comment: sorry i think which is only supported in iOS 11+ i am using an older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is no `setDocument` method, but there is a [`document`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview) property which you can use:

```
guard let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "pdf")
    else { fatalError("PDF not found") }

guard let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)
    else { fatalError("PDF document not created") }

pdfView.document = pdfDocument
```

Also, there is no need to cast the URL to NSURL and then back into a URL.

Comment: Thanks so much! I moved the code to ViewController.swift and associated it with a button and it works perfectly!!!!

Comment: @JessyRuiter You're welcome. Yes, moving it to a view controller is the right thing to do. It doesn't really have its place in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4, you can use:**

1. Import **PDFKit**
2. Copy your pdf to your project
3. Paste bellow code **(test is pdf file name)**

   ```
   let pdfView = PDFView()

   pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(pdfView)

   pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

   guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

   if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
       pdfView.document = document
   }
   ```